# Can you flip the end of a large exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, 4-manifolds, gt.geometric-topology, open-problems

> Can you flip the end of a large exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$

### Background

**Definition** (**Exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$**):
An exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ is a smooth manifold $R$ homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$, where $\mathbb{R}^4$ is equipped with its standard smooth structure.

**Definition** (**Large exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$**):
A large exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ is an exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ containing a four-dimensional compact smooth submanifold $K'$ that can not be smoothly embedded into $\mathbb{R}^4$.

**Definition** (**End of a large exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$**):
If $R$ is a large exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $D^4$ is a four-dimensional disk topologically embedded into $R$ such that $K' \subset D^4$, then $R - D^4$ is an end of $R$.

**Remark**:
The previous definition varies slightly from the standard definition of "end", however it will be used for the remainder of this question. (See [Gompf and Stipsicz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821809946) Exercise 9.4.11 for the standard definition.)

**Remark**:
If $R - D^4$ is the end of a large exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$, then $R - D^4$ is a smooth manifold that inherits a smooth structure from $R$.

**Definition** (**Flip of the end of a large exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$**):
Given $R - D^4$, the end of a large exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$, a flip of $R - D^4$ is a diffeomorphism $f: R - D^4 \rightarrow R - D^4$ that maps the "inner region" of $R - D^4$, that "near" the removed $D^4$, to the "outter region", that "near infinity", and vica-versa.

**Remark**:
The previous definition is also non-standard. I am not aware of any standard definitions that carry, more-or-less, the same meaning.

So, at this stage the meaning of the question is hopefully clear.

### Foreground

In our attempt to flip the end of a large exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ an inconvenient truth stands in our way:

**Theorem 1** (**Uncountably many flips fail**):
There are uncountably many large exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$'s that one can not flip the end of.

Quickly, let us see why this is true. Lemma 9.4.2 along with Addendum 9.4.4 of [Gompf and Stipsicz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821809946) state:

**Lemma 1**:
There exist pairs $(X,Y)$ and $(L,K)$ of smooth, oriented four-manifolds with $X$ simply connected, $Y$ and $K$ compact, $X$ and $L$ open (i.e. noncompact and boundaryless), $L$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$, and $X$ with negative definite intersection form not isomorphic to $n\langle-1\rangle$, such that $X - int(Y)$ and $L - int(K)$ are orientation-preserving diffeomorphic.

Theorem 9.4.3 of [Gompf and Stipsicz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821809946) states:

**Theorem**:
Any $L$ as appears in Lemma 1 is a large exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$.

The two statements above lead to:

**Lemma**:
One can not flip the end of any $L$ as appears in Lemma 1.

**Proof**:
Assume one could flip the end of $L$. Thus, one could use this flip to glue $L$ to the "end" of $X$ and obtain a simply connected closed smooth four-manifold with negative definite intersection form not isomorphic to $n\langle-1\rangle$. However, according to Donaldson's Theorem ([Gompf and Stipsicz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821809946) Theorem 1.2.30) there exists no such manifold. Thus, there exists no such flip. **QED**

Now we have shown that $L$ can not be flipped. Before we show how uncountably many large exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$'s can not be flipped, we need the definition:

**Definition** (**Radial Family**):
Let $R$ be an exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$. Thus, there exists a homeomorphism $h:\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow R$. Define $R_t$ as the image under $h$ of the open ball of radius $t$ centered at $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$. A radial family is a set of the form $\{R_t | 0 < t \le \infty \}$.

**Remark**:
If $R_t$ is a member of a radial family, then $R_t$ is a smooth manifold as it inherits a smooth structure from $R$

Theorem 9.4.10 of [Gompf and Stipsicz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821809946) states:

**Theorem**:
If $\{L_t | 0 < t \le \infty \}$ is a radial family for an $L$ as appears in Lemma 1 and $r$ is such that $K \subset L_r$, then $\{L_t | r \le t \le \infty \}$ is an uncountable family of non-diffeomorphic large exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$'s.

This leads directly to a proof of Theorem 1.

**Proof**:
Assume one could flip the end of $L_t$ for $r \le t \le \infty$, where all notation is as in the previous theorem. Thus, one could use this flip to glue $L_t$ to the "end" of $X$ less the image of $L - L_t$ and obtain a simply connected closed smooth four-manifold with negative definite intersection form not isomorphic to $n\langle-1\rangle$. Again, according to Donaldson's Theorem ([Gompf and Stipsicz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821809946) Theorem 1.2.30) there exists no such manifold. Thus, there exists no such flip.**QED**

Things are seeming rather hopeless at this point. In fact, things are worse
than they seem! But, before we can revel in this despair, we must introduce two 
definitions:

**Definition** (**Simply Connected at Infinity**):
Let $Z$ be a topological manifold. $Z$ is simply connected at infinity if for
any compact subset $C$ of $Z$ there exists a compact subset $C'$ of $Z$ that 
contains $C$ and is such that the inclusion $Z - C' \rightarrow Z - C$ induces
the trivial map $\pi_1(Z - C') \rightarrow \pi_1(Z - C)$.

**Definition** (**End Sum**):
Let $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ be non-compact oriented smooth four-manifolds that are
simply connected at infinity. Choose two proper smooth embeddings $\gamma_i : [0, \infty) 
\rightarrow Z_i$. Remove a tubular neighborhood of $\gamma_i((0, \infty))$ from
each $Z_i$ and glue the resulting $\mathbb{R}^3$ boundaries together respecting
orientations. The result is the end sum $Z_1 \natural Z_2$ of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$.

**Remark**:
The requirement that $Z_i$ is simply connected at infinity guarantees
that $\gamma_i$ is unique up to ambient isotopy and thus $Z_1 \natural Z_2$
is unique up to diffeomorphism ([Gompf and Stipsicz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821809946) Definition 9.4.6).

**Remark**:
If $R_1$ and $R_2$ are exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$, then they are non-compact oriented 
smooth four-manifolds that are simply connected at infinity and $R_1 \natural R_2$ 
is a smooth manifold homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$.

**Remark**:
$X$ of Lemma 1 is simply connected at infinity.

**Theorem 2**:
If $\{L_t | 0 < t \le \infty \}$ is a radial family for an $L$ as appears in 
Lemma 1 and $r$ is such that $K \subset L_r$, where $K$ is as in Lemma 1, then for
$R$ an exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $t$ such that $r \le t \le \infty$ there exists
no flip of $R \natural L_t$.

**Proof**:
The proof is basically a slight variation on the above theme. Assume one could flip
the end of $R \natural L_t$ for $r \le t \le \infty$. Thus, one could use this flip
to glue $R \natural L_t$ to the "end" of $X$ less the image of $L - L_t$ end summed
with $R$, in other words with the flip glue $R \natural L_t$ to 
$R \natural (X - (L - L_t))$, and obtain a simply connected closed smooth 
four-manifold with negative definite intersection form not isomorphic to 
$n\langle-1\rangle$. Again, according to Donaldson's Theorem 
([Gompf and Stipsicz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821809946) Theorem 1.2.30) there exists no such manifold. Thus, there
exists no such flip.**QED**

Now we can revel in this despair!

However, other ways of creating large exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$'s exist. For example, given a topologically slice knot that is not smoothly slice one can create a large exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$. (See, for example, [Davis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42624/slice-knots-and-exotic-mathbb-r4/57926#57926).) Such a large exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$, as far as I can see, might admit an end flip. But, I'm not sure. Thus, we end where we began.

### Question

> Can you flip the end of a large exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: I wonder if one can prove all large exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ are of the form $R \natural L_t$, where the notation is as in Theorem 2? One could then use Theorem 2 to answer the original question with a "No." However, I've no idea how to prove all large exotic R4 are of the form $R \natural L_t$.

Comment: Another idea would be to use $U$ universal $\mathbb{R}^4$. Theorem 2 implies $U \natural L_t$ does not flip. As $U \natural L_t = U = U \natural R$ for $R$ any large exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$, we know $U$ and $U \natural R$ do not flip. Maybe this could be used to show $R$ doesn't flip?

Answer (score 14):

As stated, your question is equivalent to the existence of a large exotic 4-ball (a smooth $D^4$ which cannot be smoothly embedded into $\mathbb{R}^4_{std}$).

The existence of a flip would give rise to an exotic $S^4$, by gluing the $D^4$ at infinity using the flip diffeomorphism. Removing a (small) standard ball from this $S^4$ gives a large exotic $D^4$, since it contains a smooth submanifold $K'$ which cannot embed in $\mathbb{R}^4_{std}$.

Conversely, if you had a large exotic $D^4$, then you could adjoin a collar neighborhood of $S^3\times \mathbb{R}$ to get an exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ which has a standard end (diffeomorphic to $S^3\times \mathbb{R}$), and therefore admits a flip.

Although I'm not an expert, I'm certain that the existence of a large exotic 4-ball is open (otherwise, the 4D smooth Schoenflies conjecture would imply the 4D smooth Poincare conjecture).

I realize that this does not answer the spirit of your question, which is whether there is a large exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ *which does not have a standard product end* and which admits a flip.

Comment: You're playin' fast-and-loose with the boundaries there, but I see what you mean. However, as you mention, this is not a *proof* that no flip exists; it's only a list of consequences of the existence of a flip.

Comment: Right Kelly, but part of the function of mathoverflow answers is to determine if a problem is open. 