# Doubly slice knots and an embedding of 4-manifold

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

It is well-known that the existence of topologically slice knot which is not smoothly slice implies the existence of exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$. For example, see [the answer of K. Davis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42624/slice-knots-and-exotic-mathbb-r4).

To prove the above statement, the key observations are:

Let $K$ be a knot in $S^3$ and $X_K=D^4\cup_{K} (2\textrm{-handle})$. Then,

(1) $K$ is topologically slice if and only if there is a topological embedding $\rho\colon X_K\to \mathbb{R}^4$.

(2) $K$ is smoothly slice if and only if there is a smooth embedding $\rho'\colon X_K\to \mathbb{R}^4$.

**Question.** Are there similar conditions to (1) and (2) for doubly slice knots? (in both category)

**Definition.** (1) A knot $K$ in $S^3$ is *topologically doubly slice* if there is a topologically unknotted 2-sphere $\Sigma$ in $S^4$ such that $K=S^3\cap \Sigma$. (Here, $S^3\subset S^4$ is the standard 3-sphere.)

(2) A knot $K$ in $S^3$ is *smoothly doubly slice* if there is a smooth unknotted 2-sphere $\Sigma$ in $S^4$ such that $K=S^3\cap \Sigma$.

It might be worth to mention that there are smoothly slice knots, which are topologically doubly slice knots, not smoothly doubly slice knots in [the recent paper of J. Meier](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.1161).

Comment: Nice question, but can I suggest you define "doubly slice"?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added the definition of topologically doubly slice knots and smoothly doubly slice knots.

Comment: It's worth commenting that Jeff Meier, in the paper you link to, points out that if the knot is doubly-slice, then the double branched cover over the knot embeds in $S^4$. But this is unlikely to be a characterization. For instance, there are knotted copies of $S^2$ in $S^4$ so that the double branched cover is still $S^4$, and presumably a cross-section of such a knotted 2-sphere would not necessarily be doubly slice.

Comment: (Above comment from a discussion with Jeff Meier, and works in either category.)