# How should I try to imagine exotic smoothness in R4?

Tags: gn.general-topology, smoothness

I am trying to wrap my mind around the concept of [exotic smoothness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_R4) in (and only in) $\mathbb{R}^4$.

I have some mathematical literature, but can anyone point to a semi-intuitive, semi-visual example? How should I begin to imagine a differentiable manifold that is homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic to Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Of course I realize that if a mathematical structure exists only in four dimensions, I will not be able to see it intuitively/visually, but what lower dimensional analogy comes closer?

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/a/57926/35687 for how to build an exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ from a knot that is topologically, but not smoothly, slice.